# Adding new rows to attribute table/changing polygon's attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, attribute-table

I'm using a shapefile of district boundaries. There are multiple districts which have the same name but belong to different provinces. In a few of these cases, the attribute table incorrectly specifies these polygons as belonging to the same district/province.

Example: Suppose we have a district with the name "A" which appears in provinces 1,2, and 3. The attribute table should have a separate row for each of these "A" districts but instead attributes all 3 polygons to province 1.

Is there any way to correct this?

I am using ArcMap 10.8.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you need to use the [Multipart To Singlepart](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/multipart-to-singlepart.htm) tool from the `Data Management toolbox`.

Then, you can use the newly created polygon layer to update the information in the attribute table and put each polygon to the correct district/province.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is good (and what I'd do). However, if you don't want to create a new layer, but would prefer to alter the existing one, you can edit it and [explode](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/editing/explode-a-multipart-feature.htm) just the polygons of interest from multi to single part

> In the Modify Features pane, Explode Explode separates the component
> parts of a multipart feature into single-part features with attribute
> values that match the original multipart feature. You can separate all
> component parts at one time or separate individual parts by clicking
> them.
>
> ### Explode features
>
> Exploding a multipart feature separates all of its component parts
> into single-part features. Feature attributes from the multipart
> feature are copied to the new features. You can choose to keep or
> discard the original multipart feature.
>
> 1. On the Edit tab, in the Features group, click Modify
>    Features. The Modify Features pane appears.
> 2. Expand Divide and click Explode. The tool opens in the pane.
> 3. Click the Features tab.
> 4. Click Active Select  and select the multipart feature you want to explode. The selection appears as a list in the pane.
> 5. To preserve the original feature and copy the parts, check Keep
>    original features.
> 6. In the pane, click Explode.